# Node.JS run function for each item in fs.readdir array

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a `fs.readdir()` function that I want to run every few hours. the reason for this is a bunch of files are sent to my box every so often and I have to run a script for each file to upload them to a db.

```
fs.readdir('some/location/',(err,files) => {
    if (files.indexOf('someFile') > -1) {
        console.log('file found')
        function1()
    }else{
        Console.log('file not found')
})
```

now I don't want to have to do the `readdir` for all 13 files that get dropped is there a way to create a list like

```
someFile = function1()
someFile2 = function2()
```

So it runs each files dedicated function for each file present on the readdir array?

```
var function1 = function........

var function2 = function... do.somethng.diferent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Create an object `{}` called `fileFunctions` that maps each file name to the function to apply.
2. Iterate over the files of the directory and apply the function matching this file name, using the object you just built, if this file name matches an entry in `fileFunctions`:

```
fileFunctions = {
  'file1' => function() {/*function to apply to file1*/},
  'file2' => function() {/*function to apply to file2*/},
   //etc..
};
fs.readdir('some/location/',(err,files) => {
    files.map((file) => {
       if(file in fileFunctions) {
            fileFunctions[file1](file1);
       }
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. sorry I realised I might not have explained, each file has a different function associated with it how do I call the function for the files that are now in the new array ```(file)```

Comment: Yea perfect had to make one slight change. Thank you for your help. Its much appreciated